# Wordpress cannot create new post or new page

Tags: wordpress, post

i'm working on last Wordpress release, wootheme and woocommerce installed.
I have an issue that i don't know how to fix it.
I can't create any new item like Page, post, products.. When i try to create a page or post or product or anything else i see that:

"You are currently editing the page that shows your latest posts."

I tried to repair database with phpmyadmin, with WP DB Manager but nothing is changed.

In wordpress forum i see that an user fixed that error, by phpmyadmin, wp_post and he sets primary to ID

alter table wp_post add primary key (id)

I tried to that too but appear an error: #1062 - Duplicate entry 'o' for key 'PRIMARY'

How can i fix it?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create an .htaccess file in your `wp-admin`  directory with the following contents:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterEngine Off
</IfModule>
```

And add this code in `wp-config.php` and set:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', TRUE ); // default is FALSE
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Savan 


I see that there are many many problems in mysql database, i'm tryingto fix tables but it's very hard...

many tables doesn't have primary key, unique key anymore... 
i'm following that official codex wordpress web page with correct table information but i have many duplicates.

Comment: Ok, i need to clean all my database tables, is very hard, i need to do it manually.

I need to fix last two tables:

wp_term_relationships and wp_term_taxonomy but i don't know how to do it.
In these tables there isn't a primary key and an index.
For example i need to set "object_id" as Primary key but there are many duplicate id, how do i know which records i can delete and which are not?

Comment: @9overflow  Hello  https://codex.wordpress.org/User:MichaelH/Terms_Tables
check this link

Comment: @SavanDholu Thanks for that codex link. Got me through the same problem in short order. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, so after testing alternative solutions i reinstalled the classic editor and it works